# Continuity of $f(x)=c^x$ for $c>0$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

What inequalities is used to show that $f(x)=c^x$ is continuous for some constant $c>0$
I am trying to use $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity.
That is

> $f$ is continuos at  $x_0$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a
>   $\delta>0$ such that $|x-x_0| < \delta$  implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<
>  \epsilon$.

So, basically how to do make sure of the following
\begin{align}
|c^x-c^{x_0}| \le a|x-x_0|=a\delta, \text{ where $a$ is some constant}
\end{align} 
 and let $\delta \le  \epsilon/a$.

My question what inequality is used to get the part $|c^x-c^{x_0}| \le a|x-x_0|$.

Comment: What is your recent definition of $c^x$? It could be $e^{x·\ln c}$, then you only have to use the continuity of the exponential function. Which then begs the question of what your latest definition of $\exp$ was.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying.  Lets assume that exponential is defined in terms of infitint series (taylor series)

Comment: Then use that $|e^{x+h}-e^x|=e^x·|e^h-1|\le e^x·\frac{|h|}{1-\frac{|h|}2}$.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. Is there a proof of this inequality somewhere or does it have a name?

Comment: This is a a standard bound. You estimate the remainder of the exponential series by a geometric series, $$|e^h-1-h-…-h^{n-1}/(n-1)!|\le |h|^n/n!·(1+|h|/(n+1)+|h|^2/(n+1)^2+…)\\=|h|^n/n!·1/(1-|h|/(n+1)).$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** You won't be able to find a single $a$ applicable for all values of $x$ and $\epsilon$ that proves continuity by taking $\delta \leq \epsilon /a$.  However, the definition does not demand that degree of uniformity:  $\delta$ is allowed to depend on both $\epsilon$ and $x$.

The problem is much easier if you allow yourself that freedom.

Comment: I think I understand that. However, I still need to figure out how to bound $|c^x-c^{x_0}| \le  a(x,c)|x-x_0|$, right? Is there such an inequality?